# Android Intent ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE

Tags: android, android-intent, bitmap

I have a simple Android app that tries to take a picture and send it to a server as HTTP POST with multipart data. The problem is that the the behavior of Androids Intent is different on some phones. When I run

```
Intent intent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
```

on HTC One (Android 4.1.1) and Sony Xperia Z1 (Android 4.4.4), it stores the image in the gallery and calls like the one below works:

```
data.getData().getPath();
```

(data is an instance of Intent), whereas when I run the same code on LG Nexus 5 (Android 4.4.4), the image is not stored, and

```
data.getData();
```

returns null.

What I need is a way to store the image (temporally), so I can transfer it to the server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like there could be a bug in the recent android stock camera, please [see this issue report](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=68936) on android. According to the bug, the `data` field returned by the camera intent could come back `null` in default behavior. (`MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT` is not used).

To guarantee you always get image, allocate a file yourself and [pass that uri in camera intent extras as `MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT`](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/camera.html#intent-image)

The best practice in allocating a temporary image file is to ensure the underlying media is mounted, see [this sample code snippet on android developer site](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/camera.html#saving-media). On a successful completion of camera intent, just use the file uri you allocated...do not use getData (could be null).